# How to copy all the files present in a GCS bucket to LINUX VM using airflow?

Tags: python, linux, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a requirement to copy all the files present in a bucket irrespective of folders or sub folders it's present in, to a Linux VM. However, when the files land in VM, they should be copied to a shared folder at the same directory level.

e.g
**In GCS**

`Bucket name: landing-gcp-cloud-12gd45`

```
file1: gs://landing-gcp-cloud-12gd45/file1/file1.csv

file2: gs://landing-gcp-cloud-12gd45/file2.csv

file3: gs://landing-gcp-cloud-12gd45/file3/file3.txt
...
```

**In Linux**

Destination `Directory: files`

```
file1: files/file1.csv

file2: files/file2.csv

file3: files/file3.txt
...
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you double check the o/p?

Answer (score 1):

To transfer GCS object to Cloud Composer local, you can use [GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/transfer/gcs_to_local.html#gcstolocalfilesystemoperator). After locally copied, you may use [sftpoperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.13/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/sftp_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.sftp_operator.SFTPOperator) to transfer to your remote server.

See working DAG below:

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.contrib.operators.sftp_operator import SFTPOperator
from airflow import DAG
from pathlib import Path

from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.gcs import GCSCreateBucketOperator, GCSDeleteBucketOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_local import GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.local_to_gcs import LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

ENV_ID = os.environ.get("cloud-composer-env-id")

PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("your-project")

DAG_ID = "gcs_upload_download"

BUCKET_NAME = f"your-bucket"

FILE_NAME = "your-object"    

PATH_TO_SAVED_FILE = "/home/airflow/gcs/data/<your-object>"

REMOTE_FILE_PATH = "/<your_local directory>/<your-object>"



with models.DAG(
    DAG_ID,
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2022,6,15),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["gcs", "example"],
) as dag:

    # [START howto_operator_gcs_download_file_task]
    download_file = GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator(
        task_id="download_file",
        object_name=FILE_NAME,
        bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        filename=PATH_TO_SAVED_FILE,
    )
    # [END howto_operator_gcs_download_file_task]
    
    put_file = SFTPOperator(
    task_id="test_sftp",
    ssh_conn_id="20220615_connection",
    local_filepath=PATH_TO_SAVED_FILE,
    remote_filepath=REMOTE_FILE_PATH,
    operation="put",
    create_intermediate_dirs=True,
    dag=dag
    )
    
    download_file >> put_file
```

Setting up your connection_id, you can put the ssh key in the [data directory](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_bucket) and put it in the `Extra` field. Make sure also that you allow ssh connections on port 22 by creating [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#scp) to avoid connection error. See below working sample connection_id:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Logs:

```
[2022-06-16, 02:18:26 UTC] {gcs.py:328} INFO - File downloaded to /home/airflow/gcs/data/monkey.jpg
[2022-06-16, 02:18:26 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1279} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=gcs_upload_download, task_id=download_file, execution_date=20220616T021822, start_date=20220616T021824, end_date=20220616T021826
[2022-06-16, 02:18:27 UTC] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-06-16, 02:18:27 UTC] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 1 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check

[2022-06-16, 02:18:31 UTC] {transport.py:1874} INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_8.4p1)
[2022-06-16, 02:18:31 UTC] {transport.py:1874} INFO - Authentication (publickey) successful!
[2022-06-16, 02:18:31 UTC] {sftp.py:158} INFO - [chan 0] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
[2022-06-16, 02:18:31 UTC] {sftp.py:143} INFO - Starting to transfer file from /home/airflow/gcs/data/monkey.jpg to <my-path>/monkey.jpg
[2022-06-16, 02:18:31 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1279} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=gcs_upload_download, task_id=test_sftp, execution_date=20220616T021822, start_date=20220616T021829, end_date=20220616T021831
[2022-06-16, 02:18:31 UTC] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-06-16, 02:18:31 UTC] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Transferred file in Cloud Composer:
[image]

Transferred file in Remote Server:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the GCSToSFTP operator? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_sftp/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @p13rr0m, I am not aware of that operator.

Answer (score 0):

Based on limited background provided(to be ran once a day), this is what i can recommend.

- Create a dag with [gcs hook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/gcs/index.html) as python operator.

  - Determine what all files have been modified(delta) based on `updated_timestamp`
- Determine where to write:

  - Use [SftpOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sftp/stable/_api/airflow/providers/sftp/index.html#module-airflow.providers.sftp) to copy between remote server.
  - use gcp/aws python sdk to download the files to the webserver running airflow(if no remote copy is required).

If additional information is provided we can recommend something more concrete.